# Applications of projective geometry

Tags: projective-geometry, applications

The [Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaucellier%E2%80%93Lipkin_linkage) illustrates practical use of an apparently theoretical fact concerning inversions in cicles. Are there applications of this type of theorems of projective geometry?

At [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt%27s_linkage) we find

> During the Industrial Revolution, mechanisms for converting rotary into linear motion were widely adopted in industrial and mining machinery, locomotives and metering devices. Such devices had to combine engineering simplicity with a high degree of accuracy, and the ability to operate at speed for lengthy periods. For many purposes approximate linear motion is an acceptable substitute for exact linear motion. Perhaps the best known example is the Watt four bar linkage, invented by the Scottish engineer James Watt in 1784.

This appears to imply that *precise* linear linkages (like the  Peaucellier–Lipkin) were also used, in addition to the approximate ones like Watt's. Which linear linkages were used?

Note.  If anyone is familiar with the remarkable book by Artobolevski
(see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2628897/72694)) available in Russian, French, and English, I would appreciate some input whether any of the thousands of devices there exploit theorems in projective geometry.

Comment: I am not sure of practical application of PLL: The only example I am aware of was to improve air circulation in British Parliament in the late 19th century.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, I thought it was used in concrete mechanisms to convert circular motion into rectilinear one, perhaps even in car engines. Is this inaccurate?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know this is inaccurate. The only real life examples I saw are basically toys. What is used in engines is still a version of Watt's linkage. I can explain why in case you are interested.

Comment: In contrast, planimeter, which is based on Green's theorem, is still used as a practical tool.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, yes, please do explain.  This may take the form of an *answer*.

Answer (score 2):

I will not address the "projective geometry" aspect, because I have no elements for that ; furthermore, I don't think it is an adequate framework for studying mechanisms in general.

What I would like to say is that converting linear motion into circular motion can be done by other mechanisms. Here is one which is probably not well known.

The example I am going to give (see Figure) comes from an amazing set of 7 books, translated from Russian

- into French named "Les mécanismes dans la technique moderne" by I. Artobolevski (Editions de Moscou, 1975) that give thousands (!) of mecanisms, some of them very clever.
- into English under the title "Mechanisms in Modern Engineering Design (Mir Editor, 1977)" by I. Artobolevsky (with a "y"). I am indebted to @dxiv who  pointed out the existence of this translation. Vol. 1, 3 and 4 are freely downlable :

(https://archive.org/details/ArtobolevskyMechanismsInModernEngineeringDesignVol1)

(https://archive.org/details/ArtobolevskyMechanismsInModernEngineeringDesignVol3)

(https://archive.org/details/ArtobolevskyMechanismsInModernEngineeringDesignVol4)

Here is mechanism #1770 (Vol. 2 p. 96) converting rotation into translation:

[image]

(My translation from French into English) :

$AB=BC=r$, $R/r=2$; $EG=FH$, $GK=HL$, $EG=GH=KL$.

The mechanism is based on Cardan circles, i.e., cogwheel #$2$, with radius $r$ rolls on cogwheel #$3$ with radius $R$. Element $1$ generates rotation torques $A$ and $B$ with respect to the fixed element and with wheel #$2$ resp. On observing relationship between the radii of #$2$ and #$3$, point $C$ belonging to wheel #$2$ moves along straight line p--p passing through point $A$. Element $4$ of the translator, which constitutes $2$ parallelogram linkage $KGHL$ and $GEFH$, generates a rotation  torque $C$  with wheel #$2$. When element $1$ turns about fixed axis $A$, element $4$ undergoes a translation move, whereas axis $EF$ of element #$4$ slides along straight line q--q, parallel to direction $KL$. Element $8$ turns about fixed axis $K$, and element $9$ about fixed axis $L$.

Comment: `I don't know if they have been translated into English` Apparently [yes](https://www.amazon.com/s/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_nine_bro_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3AI.+Artobolevsky%2Cp_n_feature_nine_browse-bin%3A3291437011&bbn=283155&sort=relevancerank&ie=UTF8&qid=1517355857&rnid=3291435011).

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for pointing it. I will correct my text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have gathered from the literature on this subject: While Watt's linkage (unlike the Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage, PLL) provides an approximate solution to the problem of converting linear motion to a circular motion, it it the one which is used in practice due to the following reasons:

1. Development of better synthetic oils (in the late 19th century) to smooth out the motion of Watt's linkage.
2. Watt's linkage consists of 4 rods (or 3, depending on what you count as a rod), while PLL consists of 7 rods. What is gained by the mathematical precision of PLL is lost due to slightly higher complexity (imperfection in each extra joint and rod contributes to accumulation of the error in the motion of the "output" joint of the linkage).
3. Lack of space in the engines where Watt's linkage is used: Every extra rod requires extra space.

One can find plenty of toy mechanisms (check youtube) which use PLL, but, in practice, the only use of PLL I am aware of goes back to the late 19th century, when PLL was used for ventilation in the new building of the British Parliament.

Comment: What kind of toy mechanisms? You mean toys being sold on the market? Also, do you know anything about applying projective geometry results like Desargues, Pappus, Pascal, etc?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: I do not know of any commercial toys, just what people build for fun or maybe for classes that they teach. Here is my favorite: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubF8iNEeij0 Sadly, I do not know any devices which use projective geometry.

Comment: Wait a minute, you can draw a conic section with the converse to Pascal.  It hasn't occurred to anybody to use this? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braikenridge%E2%80%93Maclaurin_theorem

Comment: @MikhailKatz: https://www.google.ch/patents/US5870830 but I do not know if it uses projective geometry.

Comment: There is a wonderful set of 7 books that have been translated from Russian to French named "Les mécanismes dans la technique moderne" by I. Artoboloevski (Editions de Moscou, 1975) that give thousands (!) of mecanisms, some of them very clever. I don't know if they have been translated into English. I can take and post some photographs in order to give a flavor of the book.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I have vague memory of Artbolevsky's book(s), but, to the best of my recollection, there was no practical application of the inversor mentioned there.